# Rigging objects to Second Life Armature Issue

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

[image]

In the first picture, I used the Second Life Avatar with skeleton and rigged a pair of test "feet" to the avatar. I was able to also transfer weights from the avatar to the "feet". When in pose mode, everything moves like it should.

[image]

In the second picture, I again have the Second Life Avatar with skeleton and am trying to rig the foot we wish to use. I am able to parent it to the skeleton by selecting the object (foot) and the armature, press Ctrl P and choose Armature Deform with Empty groups. When I then click the object and the legs of the Avatar, I go into Weight Paint Mode and try to transfer weights like I did with my test "feet" and I get an error stating the source mesh does not have any vertex groups. I'm at a loss as to how to give it vertex groups while not messing with the preset weights and skeleton as these must remain the same.

How do I give my foot vertex groups so that I may transfer weights from the Avatar to the foot?

Comment: If I do one foot it works fine. Once I have applied weight paints, it contorts the "feet" to move together instead of separately. Anyone know anything about weight painting and empty vertex groups?    I have a deadline of tonight. If anyone has any advice on how to manipulate one foot at a time I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have somehow fixed my issue.

I re-opened Blender and started completely over. 
Staying in scene one, I uploaded the Second Life Avatar. Then I opened the foot file I wanted to attach and rig. I realigned the foot to match exactly vertex for vertex again.

Once perfectly aligned, I pressed shift + D to duplicate it in case I somehow mangled it. I moved this to a new scene.

In the new scene, I placed a box inside my foot so that I could apply a mirror modifier to create the opposite foot. I then went into edit mode and chose faces and deleted the cube faces inside the foot so that it won't be seen in Second Life. I took a copy of the mirrored foot into scene one and aligned it to the SL Avatar.

I then chose both feet, rigged them to the armature by pressing Control + P and chose Deform with empty vertex groups.

Lastly, I chose the legs of the avatar (which included the original feet) and then chose the feet, changed to weight paint mode and chose transfer weights.

I checked the rig by going into pose mode and rotated the feet to make sure it was all working correctly. It was!